# How to root Moto G 1st Gen on Republic Wireless

Tags: rooting

I would like to find out how to root moto g on republic wireless. I looked everywhere and no one explains or describes how to do it. I am wondering if there is any way to root it.

Comment: Not an answer, but this post makes it seems like Republic is now ok with users rooting their phones. https://community.republicwireless.com/docs/DOC-2027

Comment: Looks like some people on reddit have had some success. http://www.reddit.com/r/republicwireless/comments/2m14cm/has_anyone_succeeded_in_rooting_their_moto_g/ . This is the TowelPieRoot they mention in the thread http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-x/themes-apps/root-towelpieroot-motorola-devices-t2825059

Comment: Related: [Root a Moto G running 4.4.4 KitKat](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/90002/16575) / [Root moto g with single click in pc](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/86693/16575)