# Root a Moto G running 4.4.4 KitKat

Tags: root-access, motorola-moto-g

I have a Moto G. I need to root my phone to use some apps.

Can anyone given me the steps to root a Moto G running 4.4.4 KitKat (the most safest and easyist way).

Comment: Related: [The easiest way to root a Moto G (XT1032) Android v. 5.0.2](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/107166/1465)

Answer (score 3):

How to Root Moto G

There are are three simple steps only

1. UNLOCK BOOTLOADER
2. FLASH CUSTOM RECOVERY [I USED CWM]
3. FLASH SUPERSU

DONE

Yeah ...you don't need to downgrade your bootloader which is very risky

Procedure

1. UNLOCKING BOOTLOADER :- i thinks its already explained well at different sites and motorola's site also [ i used this guide [Moto-g-unlock-bootloader-and-root](http://click.xda-developers.com/api/click?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_14194044244778&key=f0a7f91912ae2b52e0700f73990eb321&libId=c23388d0-bada-4be2-8fa5-5783c8fd6b19&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fshowthread.php%3Ft%3D2684234&v=1&out=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidpit.com%2Fmoto-g-unlock-bootloader-and-root&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fmoto-g%2Fhelp%2Fhow-to-root-moto-g-4-4-4-xt1033-t2824001&title=%5Broot%5D%20%5Brecovery%5D%20moto%20g%20%5Bworking%5D%20%7C%20Moto%20G%20%7C%20XDA%20Forums&txt=Moto-g-unlock-bootloader-and-root) only for unlocking]
2. FLASHING RECOVERY-

You need 3 things 
(a) motorola usb drivers [download from [here](http://click.xda-developers.com/api/click?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_14194044727259&key=f0a7f91912ae2b52e0700f73990eb321&libId=c23388d0-bada-4be2-8fa5-5783c8fd6b19&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fshowthread.php%3Ft%3D2684234&v=1&out=https%3A%2F%2Fmotorola-global-portal.custhelp.com%2Fapp%2Fanswers%2Fdetail%2Fa_id%2F88481&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fmoto-g%2Fhelp%2Fhow-to-root-moto-g-4-4-4-xt1033-t2824001&title=%5Broot%5D%20%5Brecovery%5D%20moto%20g%20%5Bworking%5D%20%7C%20Moto%20G%20%7C%20XDA%20Forums&txt=here) ]
(b) adb drivers (download from [here](http://click.xda-developers.com/api/click?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_141940448613310&key=f0a7f91912ae2b52e0700f73990eb321&libId=c23388d0-bada-4be2-8fa5-5783c8fd6b19&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fshowthread.php%3Ft%3D2684234&v=1&out=http%3A%2F%2Ffiles.androidpit.info%2Fcontent%2Fadb-tools_treiber.zip&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fmoto-g%2Fhelp%2Fhow-to-root-moto-g-4-4-4-xt1033-t2824001&title=%5Broot%5D%20%5Brecovery%5D%20moto%20g%20%5Bworking%5D%20%7C%20Moto%20G%20%7C%20XDA%20Forums&txt=here) ]
(c) Custom recovery (download from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2563599) ] i used cwm without touch OR USE PHILZ RECOVERY (4.4.4) [CLICK HERE TO DOWNLOAD](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2201860)

Real procedure:-

1. install motorola usb drivers
2. extract adb drivers anywhere in your computer
3. copy recovery.img [i renamed it to only recovery] into adb tools folder
4. boot your phone into fastboot mode by pressing volume down key and pressing power key simultaneously , and then releasing power key .
5. connect your moto g to your computer through data cable
6. go into adb tools folder => while pressing shift key => right click => and click open cmd here !
7. type [fastboot flash recovery recovery.img] and press enter { IGNORE Mismatched partition size' AFTER FLASHING RECOVERY }

DONE  just press volume down and then volume up to boot into cwm

3. FLASHING SUPER SU
4. DOWNLOAD THIS FILE FROM [HERE](http://click.xda-developers.com/api/click?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_141940454221111&key=f0a7f91912ae2b52e0700f73990eb321&libId=c23388d0-bada-4be2-8fa5-5783c8fd6b19&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fshowthread.php%3Ft%3D2684234&v=1&out=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediafire.com%2Fdownload%2F8s6es87e1uzxwdb%2FSuperSU-v1.86.zip&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.xda-developers.com%2Fmoto-g%2Fhelp%2Fhow-to-root-moto-g-4-4-4-xt1033-t2824001&title=%5Broot%5D%20%5Brecovery%5D%20moto%20g%20%5Bworking%5D%20%7C%20Moto%20G%20%7C%20XDA%20Forums&txt=HERE)
5. PUT IT IN INTERNAL MEMORY

PROCEDURE => IN CWM =>INSTALL FROM SD CARD => CHOOSE SUPER SU => RESTART 
It will ask 'root is broken' WHEN REBOOTING FROM CWM. CHOOSE YES
DONE !

I recommend these apps you should install first after rooting

1. Greenify (getting awesome battery backup )
2. xposed installer
3. gravitybox
4. tinted status bar (i love this module..make your android like ios7)
5. Titanium Backup

Comment: Couple questions: Can one use the [Play Store SuperSU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu) instead of installing the linked file with the custom recovery?  Is the only reason for using the custom recovery to install the SuperSU program from a file? Sorry I'm confused what exactly the custom recovery does differently, and what does the linked SuperSU do differently? Thanks!

Comment: Think of the SuperSU application as being a sort of graphical front-end for the su binary.

Because of the way directory/file permissions are configured on Android, you need to have the su binary on your /system partition in order for it to work. Putting elsewhere will not suffice, because it will not have the permissions it needs to actually allow processes to switch users.

Normal applications (without root) cannot write to/system, so the SuperSU application itself cannot simply install su where it needs to be. This is the reason why you will not have root if you install SuperSU from the Pla