# The easiest way to root a Moto G (XT1032) Android v. 5.0.2

Tags: rooting, 5.0-lollipop, root-access, motorola-moto-g, superuser

I have just rooted a samsung Lite 3 tablet...and it was simple. Really simple. Used Odin to install CWM, then installed a superuser app from a zip file. Really straightforward.

So I decided to look into how to root and get super user access to my Moto G. That's when I realized that rooting a moto G and getting super user access will be a pain.

Does anyone have a straightforward description with the apps/zips necessary to root and gain super user access to a moto G XT1032?

Cheers

Comment: Related: [Root a Moto G running 4.4.4 KitKat](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/90002/1465)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Steps :**

- 1. Install custom recovery **TWRP**([**Download link**](http://techerrata.com/file/twrp2/xt1032/openrecovery-twrp-2.8.1.0-xt1032.img))
- 2. [Install SuperSU from recovery](https://download.chainfire.eu/636/SuperSU)

also, take a look at this :

[[GUIDE] Root **XT1032**/XT1033 Moto G Running Android Lollipop](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/help/guide-root-xt1032-xt1033-moto-g-running-t2965507)

just do it with above link instruction.

Comment: But the SuperSU cant be installed without a custom ROM, right? So, I will need to install CWM to onlock the bootloader (if I am not wrong). But it seems to be pretty difficult to install CWM on moto Gs. Odin only works with samsung phones, right?

Comment: There is two SuperSu - (apk file - Zip file) and you need to `zip` file for install on custom recovery.yes, you need custom recovery.Odin for samsung, yes.use below link for install custom recovery - you need to `ADB & Fastboot tools`  for install if your bootloader is unlocked : [Custom Recovery for Moto G Running Lollipop](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/general/guide-custom-recovery-moto-g-xt1033-t2972905) another questions in **ASK Question** .this link show you , how you can install the custom recovery.TWRP - Philz touch or other something...

Comment: @Elysium Zip flashing is the prerogative of custom recovery. Custom ROM (not CWM) doesn't do anything in it. SuperSU zip can be flashed easily on any ROM using a custom recovery (TWRP here).